# Covariant and Directional Covariant Derivative (of Tensors)

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

I'm trying to write precise coordinate and coordinate-free definitions for the covariant and directional covariant derivative of a tensor. I have some working definitions from lecture, but I feel like they could be made better (also I'm not too sure how to write both coordinate and coordinate free definitions for either of these).

**Covariant Derivative**

The covariant derivative of a tensor field $T$ with respect to a linear connection $\nabla$, is $$\nabla T = \nabla_{E_i}T\otimes \theta^i$$ where $\{E_i\}$ forms a local frame, $\{\theta^i\}$ its dual co-frame, and $\nabla_{E_i}(T)$ is the directional covariant derivative.

**Directional Covariant Derivative**

Let $T$ and $S$ be tensors, then the directional covariant derivative, $\nabla_X$, has the defining property $$\nabla_X(T\otimes S)=\nabla_XT \otimes S + T\otimes \nabla_XS.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wording "directional covariant derivative" is not widely used in the literature, but some authors (e.g. Amari, Information Geometry and Its Applications, p. [117](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=UkSFCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117)) use it, perhaps, to distinguish from the "total covariant derivative" (see e.g. J.M.Lee, Riemannian Manifolds: An Introduction to Curvature, p. [54](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=92PgBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54)), which is a tensor $\nabla T$ of a higher rank, given by
$$
\nabla T (\omega_1, \dots, \omega_p, V_1, \dots, V_q, X) = \nabla_X T (\omega_1, \dots, \omega_p, V_1, \dots, V_q)
$$
As I get it, if $\nabla T$ denotes the total covariant derivative as above, then $\nabla_{X} T$ is the directional covariant derivative of $T$ in the direction of vector field $X$, and $\nabla_X T (\dots) = \nabla T (\dots, X) $.